# File system like structure with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, filesystems, structure

I want to build a file system like structure with MongoDB.

Here are the rules:

- the top most entity is a project
- folders can be direct descendants of projects or other folders
- files can be direct descendants of projects or folders

Basically, this is what I want:

```
project: {
    folders: [{
          folders: [{
                folders: [{
                      ...
                }],
                files: []
          }],
          files: []
    }],
    files: []
}
```

So as I see it, I have three options:

1.) Define a SQL type structure where every entity lives within it's own collection.

- pros: "standard" organization with separation of concerns
- cons: absolute query hell, slow, no support for paths, a need for implementation of transactions

2.) Define one structure (like the above example), where everything lives within the `project` entity.

- pros: clean and self-explanatory organization
- cons: hard querying (things need to be queried and manipulated in the application layer and not so much the DB layer), things are not clearly separated because everything lives within one entity (is that a true con?), document size of 16 MB limit enforced by the system, accessing one document so often seems at least problematic if not catastrophic :)

3.) Define a hybrid structure with three entities, but where folders can live within other folders:

```
projects: []

folders: [{
    folders: [{
          folders: [{
              ...
          }]
      }]
}]

files: []
```

- pros: relatively clean and self-explanatory organization, relatively simple querying (although it requires a lot of application level querying and manipulation), almost (good enough) a "standard" organization with separation of concerns
- cons: a need for implementation of transactions

I tried to implement all three. At this point, the third solution seems the best. I would really appreciate everyone's input on this. Has anybody tried to achieve something similar?

Comment: How is your application going to access your data ?

Comment: Building on Node.js and Mongoose. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I mean, what queries do you intend to write. Are you just going to filter on file name or do you need match to the entire folder structure as well ? See https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/ for some more information.

Comment: Why do you want to have a file system like structure? Is that something specif of your business logic or are you just implementing it in order to hold paths regarding files on your server?

Comment: Yes, it's my business logic. In the end I solved it with materialized paths. A very elegant solution :)

Comment: I had been struggling with this for a while, but then I found Materialized Paths on MongoDB, link [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/).
This is the most simple solution I could find, basically, all you do is create the schema where the _id is something unique about your tree structure, and a path that includes all parent ids like the example given in the documentation, you can also add other fields/properties to the schema.